# How to approximately compare JSON object literals using Chai or vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript

Consider an `expected` and `actual` value of a JSON object literal:

```
        let expectedResult = {
                [0.9272952180016122, 1.1760052070951352, 1.0808390005411683],
                [1.2870022175865687, 0.8097835725701669,  1.240498971965643],
                [1.3494818844471053, 1.014197008784674,  1.3894765523934063]
            ],
            'spectrum': [
                [ 5, 13, 17],
                [25, 29, 37],
                [41, 53, 61]
            ]
        };

        let actualResult = {
                [0.9272952180016122, 1.1760052070951352, 1.0808390005411683],
                [1.2870022175865687, 0.8097835725701669,  1.240498971965643],
                [1.3494818844471053, 1.014197008784674,  1.3894765523934063]
            ],
            'spectrum': [
                [ 5, 13, 17],
                [25, 29, 37],
                [41, 53, 61]
            ]
        };
```

The second entry differs :  `1.1760052070951352` vs `1.176005207095135` .   Is there any construct to handle this comparison either in javascript or Chai?

The following does not work since it ends up being an object comparison

```
    chai.expect(actualResult).to.be.closeTo(expectedResult);
```

> AssertionError: expectedResult { Object (real, imag, ...) } to be a number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This function apparently is slated for `chai5` .  https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/644 .

> the plan is to have this behaviour in Chai 5. You're welcome to make plugins that accept Sinon matchers for now - but be warned it may be obsolete by the time Chai 5 comes out

Here is a workaround in the meantime

> I ended up implementing @vaskevich approach as a plugin. It even replaces this potentially confusing text about stubs being called. Here it is:

```
chai.use((_chai, utils) => {
  chai.Assertion.addMethod('matchEql', function fn(expectedMatch) {
    const subject = utils.flag(this, 'object');
    const stub = sinon.stub();
    stub(subject);
    try {
      sinon.assert.calledWithMatch(stub, expectedMatch);
    } catch (error) {
      error.name = 'MatchAssertionError';
      error.message = error.message.replace(
        /^expected stub to be called with match/,
        `expected ${utils.objDisplay(subject)} to match`
      );
      throw error;
    }
  });
});
```